# How to store checked or unchecked events of a checkbox in angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular, checkbox

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="container">
      <div *ngFor="let initial of initialState,let j = index" >
          <div *ngIf="initial>0">


              <button class="button" type="button">Device {{j}}</button>
              &nbsp; 
              <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox_category" checked (change)="search(initial, $event)" />
                  <div class="slider round"></div>
              </label>
          <br/> 
          </div>

          <div *ngIf="initial===0">
              <button class="button" type="button">Device {{j}}</button>
              &nbsp; 
              <label class="switch">
                  <input type="checkbox"  id="checkbox_category" (change)="search(initial, $event)" />
                  <div class="slider round"></div>
              </label>
          <br/> 
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button class="button" type="button">Submit</button>
 </form>

export class DashboardComponent{

  initialState:any = [1,1,1,0,0,0,1];
  intendedDeviceStatus: any = this.initialState;

  search(category:any, event:any) {

        var index = this.initialState.indexOf(category);
        this.intendedDeviceStatus[index]= (~this.intendedDeviceStatus[index]);      

}
```

In the above code I have a `Initailstatus` array which gives me which `checkboxes` are checked and unchecked ....based on that after displaying checkboxes. After Displaying it when I change checked checkbox to uncheck it not getting updated in `IntendedDevicesArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Because initialState is array of number not object. so the method array.indexOf(value) with find the first element that equal the value. therefore, it return wrong index;

Example:

```
var a = [1,1,1,0, 0 ,0,1];
var b = a[2];
var c = a.indexOf(b); c = 0 not 2
```

To make your code work.
change from
`<input ... (change)="search(initial, $event)" />`
 to
`<input ... (change)="search(j, $event)" />`

and change search function:

```
search(index:number, event:any) {
    this.intendedDeviceStatus[index]= this.intendedDeviceStatus[index] ? 1 : 0;
```

}

Beside that, I suggest you use initialState as boolean array insteal of number.
user *ngIf="initial" for checked and *ngIf="!initial" for unchecked. in search function

```
this.intendedDeviceStatus[index] = !this.intendedDeviceStatus[index];
```

if you want to your code for more short and better, you can write directive that support two way binding for input tag.